# How to organize Qt DLLs with Qt-based dependency

Tags: c++, qt, dll, project-organization

I have a Qt application using Qt 4.8.5. This application is dependent on a DLL that was built using Qt 4.6.0. Let's call it "MyDLL.dll".

I cannot rebuild MyDLL.dll to update it to a more current version of Qt. Since both my application and MyDLL require the QtCore and other DLLs, and the versions are different, how do I organize my files such that they don't conflict?

MyDLL is required at startup, so I can't use any delay load methodologies.

edit: To be clear, this question came up because the MyDll.dll was built using a custom Qt 4.6.0 from modified source, and my application is using a custom build of 4.8.5. The modifications weren't necessarily the same in both versions, so I didn't want to assume that I could still use the 4.8.5 DLLs. Turned out that it worked out in this case, but the question stands.

Comment: Qt maintains binary compatibility over minor releases, so you should be able to just use MyDLL.dll with Qt 4.8.5. Did you try?

Comment: I did not, actually, and you're right that there should be binary compatibility - one of the more awesome things about Qt. I guess I oversimplified my question. It completely mystifies me that Windows doesn't allow an executable to point to a particular DLL subdirectory.

Comment: Windows does allow that. First it searches for DLLs in the executable's directory, then the current working directory, then it searches system directories then the PATH in order (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7d83bc18.aspx). If you need to override versions of DLLs that are in your PATH, put them in the same directory as the executable, or set the current working directory to whatever subdir your DLLs are in before running the program (e.g. in a shortcut), but you don't need to do any of this anyways. You'll be fine, there's no "DLL Hell" or anything else going on here.

Comment: Personally, I consider modifying the PATH variable on the global scope to be an extremely dangerous practice. My computer often tries to mix Qt versions because one or two careless programmers had their installers modify global PATH. Can you point me to a link for setting the working directory in a shortcut? That sounds promising.

Comment: In the explorer GUI, when you create a shortcut, if you right click and choose "properties", the "startup directory" setting specifies the initial working directory. To automate this, it depends on your installer (for example, Nullsoft's NSIS installer system has a command to create a shortcut to your application, and the working directory for the shortcut is one of the parameters). Creating a shortcut programmatically is possible (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Shellink_Creating_Shortcut), easiest option is to do it with your installer.

Comment: However, please note, if placing DLLs in your executable's directory is *not* sufficient, and you find yourself having to do tricks with the current working directory and PATH, there is probably a bigger issue that you should step back and examine first. Only in very odd or unfortunate circumstances would you be justified in placing auto load DLLs in unusual places. The case you described with Qt and your custom DLL is neither odd nor unfortunate. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be having any issues. Qt maintains binary compatibility over minor and patch releases (see http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Version-Compatibility) and an application/DLL built with 4.6.x will run fine when bound to 4.8.x runtime.

- Your MyDLL.dll built with 4.6.0 will run with 4.8.5 runtime DLLs.
- Your application built with 4.8.5 will run with 4.8.5 runtime DLLs.
- Your application will run fine with MyDLL.dll as long as you are using the same interface you've always been using.

If you are seeing issues it is because of something else, and you will need to clarify exactly what problem you are having.

If you are not seeing issues and are just asking preemptively, then 1) just proceed as normal with no special considerations, and 2) you should have tried it first!

Comment: I am not encountering any errors per se, but rather anticipating issues potentially caused by mixing Qt versions. I also loathe having a massive pile of DLLs in my bin directory and hoped there might be a way around it because I have several other dependencies on top of MyDLL.

Comment: There will be no issues as long as you don't mix major versions (e.g. Qt 4.x and 5.x will not mix - you *are* locked in to 4.x).

Comment: I consider this the correct answer to my question. Although the other answer addresses the issue of DLL Hell in a more detailed manner, it's not the issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to DLL Hell! :(

This is a huge problem under Microsoft windows, since the standard isn't to build version information into the DLL file name (like with Linux .so files).

You won't be able to accomplish what you are after if you link directly against "MyDLL.dll" since it will be looking for QT DLLs (like QtCore, QtGui, etc). The stock Qt DLLs contain no version decoration in the filename, so there will be a conflict as to which one to load. Also, you will likely not be able to link correctly in the first place (due to the conflicts. Qt doesn't play well with older versions).

The only possibility might be to create a separate executable that links against Qt 4.6.0 and MyDLL, and use some out-of-process communication between your main app and the server. COM might work in this case, but it largely depends on what your dll actually does.

The only other course of action would be to downgrade your main application and fix it at Qt 4.6.0.

Comment: Two things: .so files have the same issue (it's a consequence of shared libraries in general), Windows just encourages generally poor organization of DLLs. Version information is embedded in DLLs, and is often provided by the vendor as functions in the DLL as well, it's just usually ignored by applications. But in any case, Qt maintains binary compatibility across releases, the OP shouldn't be having any issues.

Comment: Very true that there is version information built into the DLL, but it doesn't do you much good if you have linked using an import library and aren't loading the dll dynamically.

However, good point about backward compatibility. It would be interesting to see what error message he has actually getting.

Comment: By the way, Qt embeds the major version number in the DLL filename for that reason. The issues you describe are valid but not applicable to Qt runtime or the OP's issue. You know this, I only point it out because I don't want the OP to go down a path of DLL paranoia. :) We need more information about the problem he was seeing; theoretically there shouldn't have been any issues.

Comment: Yes, it embeds the major version (4) but not the minor nor release, which isn't helping him at the moment.

I do agree that we need more information.

Comment: Minor and release versions are binary compatible, that's why it only embeds the major. The developers of Qt for Windows put exactly the same protection that many (but not all) developers put into their .so's.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Jason. I will look into this and test it when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Jason C's answer got it right. Also note the following:

1. MyDll.dll must be compiled with the same compiler version as the rest of your application.
2. The version of Qt used to build MyDll.dll should have had the same major configuration flags as the version of Qt that you're currently using. Things such as Qt namespaces, QThread support, etc. must all be the same.